# Why is what may be one of the most useful reinterpret cast behavior use cases considered undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, reinterpret-cast

For some trivial type `T`, and for a pointer expression that is suitably aligned and refers to a region at least as large as `T`, can anyone tell me why is a `*reinterpret_cast<T const *>(expr)` not simply defined to do the same thing as `memcpy`?

I totally understand how it might be UB if `T` were not trivial, or if expr did not meet `T`'s alignment criteria, so that's not an issue in my question.  I also am not asking if it is UB, because I already know that it is.  I am asking what the rationale for leaving such usage of `reinterpret_cast` as UB is, given that calling `memcpy` apparently does exactly the same thing as calling the copy constructor for the trivial type anyways (re: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#2 and http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#3)

In terms of practical usage, it seems like all the compilers that support C++11 and later do exactly this anyways, so it's not the case that this is UB is actually stopping me from doing what I might otherwise want to do, but I'm wondering what possible reason there could be to leave it as undefined by the standard?

Comment: Consider an architecture where doing that operation would cause a hardware fault.  Because of such an architecture, faulting when doing exactly that is an acceptable outcome... because it is undefined behavior.  If the standard made rules that such behavior was not allowed, a major safety feature of that architecture would have to be disabled for C++.

Comment: How could it cause a hardware fault when calling memcpy itself would not have caused undefined behavior if the destination were used, however?

Comment: The destination memory would be tagged as a read/write buffer of bytes, with the size of `T`.  The source memory would be tagged with as being the trivial type `T`.

Comment: What is the point of reinterpret_cast if to not treat memory that may have been tagged with a different type as being tagged with some other type?

Comment: There is a whole bunch of reasons for using [reinterpret_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).  The only one I've used it for is converting an "opaque pointer" (a `void*`) used through a C API back as a user-supplied associated value with a callback function to its actual type.

Comment: Not all such usages result in an (equivalent of) `memcpy()`.     Use the expression to initialise a reference `const T &ref = *reinterpret_cast<T const *>(expr)` and there are plenty of cases where using the reference gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Many things in C and C++ are UB because the term was originally used to mean that the Standard waived jurisdiction to allow implementations to process code in whatever way would best serve their customers; the less likely it was that there would be any advantage to doing anything unusual, the less need there was to actually define the behavior.  Reclassifying actions which implementations had been expected to process consistently at least 100% of the time, but which "modern" compilers have started processing weirdly, would imply a judgment that the Committee knew more about...

Comment: ...what implementations' customers need than the authors of the implementations, or else that some compiler writers are contemptuous toward their customers' needs.  Unfortunately, those compiler writers have veto power over anything that would make them look bad.

Comment: @Peter: If the Standard had specified that the reference may be used to access trivial objects of either the old or new type, how many useful optimizations would have been forbidden by such a guarantee?  Clang and gcc have adopted an abstraction model that would make it difficult for them to uphold that guarantee without sacrificing some other optimizations, but I don't think the Standard was ever intended to encourage compiler writers to implement such a model.